# ItextSharp exception: The document has no catalog object (meaning: it's an invalid PDF)

Tags: asp.net, itext

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(766, 1500);
Document document = new Document(rec);
document.SetMargins(22, 22, 22, 22);
string pdfPath = Server.MapPath("~/Export/" + strAccount + "/Exports/" + strAgentID) + "/" + strReportName + ".pdf";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
document.Open();

HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

var cssResolver //= new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
    = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);

var pipeline =

    new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,

            new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext,

                new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);

XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

TextReader tr = new StringReader(htmlFileData);
p.Parse(tr);
document.Close();

//********************* Add text watermark for pdf created above ************************************************************

string strPDFPath = Server.MapPath("~/Export" + "/" + strAccount + "/Exports/" + strAgentID + "/" + strReportName + ".pdf");
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strPDFPath);
FileStream stream = new FileStream(strPDFPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream);
for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
{
    Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);
    PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(pageIndex);
    pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 40);
    PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
    graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.4F;
    pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
    pdfData.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
    pdfData.BeginText();
    pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "FOR BETA TEST ONLY", pageRectangle.Width / 2, pageRectangle.Height / 2, 45);
    pdfData.EndText();
}
pdfStamper.Close();
stream.Close(); 

//******************************************************************************
```

In above code, `pdf` successfully created but an exception occurs in the block where we are trying to add watermark.
    In watermark assignment block, strPDFPath give accurate path in the form as
    `D:\\MyTestProject\\Reports\\Export\\SIP\\Exports\\BEEC1308\\1004MC_RevA.pdf` which is exact location of file. If I open this
    path in browser then I'm getting correct PDF. But when I'm reading the file path using
    `PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strPDFPath);` raises above mentioned `exception`. Where above code going wrong or is there need to combine watermark and `PDF` creation both in single block.

Comment: Try stamping to a different file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from and writing to the same PDF at the same time. I'm assuming that instead of this:

```
//Incorrect
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strPDFPath);
```

You want to do this:

```
//Correct
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
```